# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `delivery_date' for #<Order:0x007f4641e56198>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, undefined, actionview

When I deploy to heroku and I try to create a new order, which is nested in merchants, I get "We're sorry! Something went wrong!" page. It was working fine on localhost but not in heroku. I have done "Heroku run rake db:migrate" and "heroku restart", but that didn't solve the problem. I am a newbie in rails/heroku and I do not know how to verify the column exist in heroku DB. I'd really appreciate your help.

This was the error I got:

```
    ←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:48.756234+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:48.756243+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"merchant_id"=>"3"}
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:48.794320+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered orders/_form.html.erb (15.1ms)
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:48.794384+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.1ms)
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:48.794541+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms
←[33m2014-07-23T05:52:49.199614+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/merchants/3/orders/new" host=doordemo-2014.herokuapp.com request_id=ac94d5ce-f387-4cdd-9816-49b3
83d0c0b3 fwd="115.132.128.218" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=43ms status=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.156723+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/merchants/3/orders/new" for 115.132.128.218 at 2014-07-23 05:52:49 +0000
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192498+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192506+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     16:     <%= f.label :delivery_date %>
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.159989+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"merchant_id"=>"3"}
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192544+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/orders/_form.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_orders__form_html_erb___3947962364785509298_69969865024340'
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192545+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/orders/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_orders__form_html_erb___3947962364785509298_69969865024340'
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.159930+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.190336+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.189961+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered orders/_form.html.erb (3.6ms)
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.190131+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192502+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `delivery_date' for #<Order:0x007f4641e56198>):
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192546+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/orders/new.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_orders_new_html_erb___3734469813804991169_69969865000700'
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192503+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     14:
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192542+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     20:   <div class="form-group">
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192505+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     15:   <div class="form-group">
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192549+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192508+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     17:     <%= f.text_field :delivery_date, :placeholder => "DD/MM/YYYY", class: "form-control" %>
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192510+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     18:   </div>
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192548+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-07-23T05:52:49.192511+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     19:
←[33m2014-07-23T05:52:49.899149+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=doordemo-2014.herokuapp.com request_id=8c56c058-361e-4399-94f8-8ddff39347df fw
d="115.132.128.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
```

_form partial

```
<%= form_for([@merchant, @order]) do |f| %> <!--Trial 1-->
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger dismissable">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :delivery_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :delivery_date, :placeholder => "DD/MM/YYYY", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :delivery_time %>
    <%= f.text_field :delivery_time, :placeholder => "HH:MM AM/PM", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :delivery_address %> <span style="color: #CC3300;">(We only deliver to Lintas, Damai & Kota Kinabalu)<span>
    <%= f.text_area :address, rows: 3, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :payment_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit 'Place Order', class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: does delivery_date column belongs to order table?

Comment: check that all migrations were run on server

Comment: Hello Ahmad & @gotva. How do i go about doing this? I could post something else if needed for you to understand it more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DB**

It seems you already know the problem will likely (almost certainly) caused by your database not having the `delivery_date` column / attribute.

As the error explains,

```
undefined method `delivery_date'
```

This essentially means that your `model` will not have the `delivery_date` attribute, which means when you try and call it from your view / controller, it's going to think you have no method for it.

---

**Fix**

Bottom line is you need to be able to add the `delivery_date` column to your corresponding table.

The simple fix is to perform a migration on your database, considering you have the migration set up already for the column):

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

To test whether you *have* the column/attribute, the best way is to use the [`attribute_names`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attribute_names) in your `Heroku` rails console:

```
$ heroku run rails c
$ [MODEL].attribute_names
$ #-> attribute names outputted. Check for delviery_date
```

--

If you don't have a migration set up for your table, you'll basically just need to initiate a new migration locally & then populate it with the following:

```
#dg/migrate/your_new_migration.rb
add_column :datatable, :delviery_date, :string
```

Comment: Hello Rich, I tried running [ORDER].attribute_names. It's giving me RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ORDER. what should i do?

Comment: Sorry Rich, now I am seeing the attribute names and yes, I did not see delivery_date. I will try initiating the new migration.

Comment: I tried to add the new migration and use rake db:migrate locally, and I got an error due to duplicated names. So do I just skip rake db:migrate here and just push this to github and heroku? then do the heroku run rake db:migrate?

Comment: Solved! Thanks Rich :)